# ALSA error when using PyAudio and SpeechRecognition: PaAlsaStreamComponent_BeginPolling: Assertion `ret == self->nfds' failed

Tags: python

So I was making a virtual assistant using Conda and SpeechRecognition with PyAudio but when i use the SpeechRecognition.Microphone class the script crashes with the error

```
PaAlsaStreamComponent_BeginPolling: Assertion `ret == self->nfds' failed.
```

Is there any way to fix this?
Thanks!

PD: I have already tried `sudo alsa force-reload` and `sudo reboot`.

Answer (score 0):

try  `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio`